# Why Pr[C = 1∣M = a] = 1 ≠ 0 = Pr[C = 1∣M = b]?

Tags: encryption

The statement is false. We show this by providing a counter-example.

Define

- **M = {a, b}**,
- **K = {k1, k2}**,
- **C = {0, 1}**.

Let **Enc(k, a) = 0** and **Enc(k, b) = 1 for k = k1, k2**.

Dec algorithm will return an on input ciphertext 0 and b on input ciphertext 1. Clearly, the scheme is correct.

**Pr[C = 1∣M = a] = 1 ≠ 0 = Pr[C = 1∣M = b]**,
thus showing that the scheme is not perfectly secret.

Why **Pr[C = 1∣M = a] = 1 and Pr[C = 1∣M = b] = 0**? 
I think it should be Pr[C = 1∣M = a] = 0 ≠ 1 = Pr[C = 1∣M = b].

Comment: @fgrieu the vertical bar is generally used to denote conditional probabilities.

Comment: @Maeher: Ah,eclipse of the mind, because recently I've been seeing a lot of [conditional probabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability) with the assumption in subscript, as in $(\Pr_{M=a}[C=1]=1)≠(0=\Pr_{M=b}[C=1])$. I'm still not sure about the parsing of the center.

Comment: Where does this statement come from? Yes, for the example you provide it's obviously incorrect. Most likely someone somewhere accidentally swallowed zero and one.

Comment: That was supposed to read "swapped", I do not recommend swallowing bits.